# How to exit action group or cancel the installation through run script java code in install4j

Tags: user-interface, install4j

Hiii,
I have run script code in one action group where i have my java code, is there is any way to exit the action group conditionally through java code means condition wise it will be decided whether to exit action group or continue.

Is there is any way to cancel installation through java code based on condition or navigate to particular screen conditionally i have this script under installation action.

context.cancel() didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action groups have a "On error break group" property. If set, any failed action will break out of the action group, for example if you return `false` from a "Run script" action.